# Is there a semi-dense deuterium state?

Tags: science-based, space-travel, rockets, fuels, fusion

**Deuterium as Fusion Fuel**

For a future fusion thruster I was going to use a deuterium fusion drive similar to the Epstein drive from the Expanse. I've looked into the fuel sources online as well as Project Rho. I came across ultra-dense deuterium which is fairly mysterious since there is only 1 real source on it.

The basic idea I like about it is that it would save room on a ship as well as the strength of the lasers needed to ignite fusion. What I am wondering is if it is an either or thing: is there either regular deuterium and ultra dense deuterium, or is there a middle ground for a semi-ultra dense deuterium?

Comment: What do you mean by "either regular deuterium and ultra-dense deuterium"? Deuterium is deuterium. *If* ultra-dense deuterium exists (and [most people don't believe it exists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36064/is-ultradense-deuterium-real)), ultra-dense deuterium would be just regular deuterium in a specific state of aggregation. It's like saying that water is either regular water of ultra-thin water (aka, vapor). (And anyway, there is a dedicated [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com) for such questions.)

Comment: "*Is there a semi-dense deuterium state?*" - Answer: No.

Comment: I am wondering if there is any theoretical reason that would cause the Ultra-Dense Deuterium (if it could exist) to be the only stable density asides from the regular density of deuterium. In the story, it would essentially create a metallic deuterium pellet that would then be sent out the back of the ship and hit with several lasers to ignite the fusion explosion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not explicitly being a pure, dense state of deuterium, this may be a possibility to save space.
A type of materials that has been considered for hydrogen (and hence Deuterium) storage are [metal hydrides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_storage#Metal_hydrides) , [some of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palladium_hydride) can can adsorb about 900 times their volume of hydrogen. One in particular that is being considered for a potential [hydrogen fuel](https://ardica.com/solutions/)  storage is [aluminium hydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_hydride#Fuel) (some times called Alane), as it contains twice the hydrogen density of liquid hydrogen, and due to it decomposing back to aluminium and hydrogen at 100°C, the hydrogen is easily extracted.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Deuterium is just deuterium. Or, you could think of it as an ultra-dense version of hydrogen! In that case, you could use tritium, which works well as a radioactive isotope of hydrogen!